# c++ class error - immutable

Tags: c++, immutability

I have written a class where the objects and class attributes are immutable - however each time I attempt to update a class attribute I get the following error;

"Unhandled exception ... in ConsoleApplication.exe ... Stack overflow"

Some details on the class object. The header file of the class,

```
class AnObject {

public:

//constructor
AnObject();

AnObject(
    const std::string           AttributeA,
    const __int32               AttributeB
    )

const AnObject AnObject::SetAttributeA(const std::string AttributeA) const;
const AnObject AnObject::SetAttributeB(const __int32 AttributeB) const;
const AnObject AnObject::SetMyAttributes (const std::string AttributeA, const __int32 AttributeB) const;

private:

const std::string           AttributeA;
const __int32               AttributeB;
};
```

The class file,

```
AnObject::AnObject() : AttributeA("1002"), AttributeB(1) {};
AnObject::AnObject( const std::string AttributeA, const __int32 AttributeB) : AttributeA("1002"), AttributeB(1) 
{ 
SetMyAttributes("1002", 1);
};

const AnObject AnObject::SetMyAttributes(const std::string  AttributeA, const __int32AttributeB)
const 
{
try {
            return AnObject
        (
                // base fields
                AttributeA, AttributeB
        )
 } 
catch (exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
};
```

The object is immutable and hence all parameters set when changing a parameter by the setter class. However the code generates an error when I call the methods within main.

Comment: You are calling the constructor recursively :-P ...

Answer (score 1):

THis constructor of yours:

```
AnObject::AnObject( const std::string AttributeA, const __int32 AttributeB)
```

calls

```
SetMyAttributes("1002", 1);
```

which calls the constructor again...

```
const AnObject AnObject::SetMyAttributes(const std::string  AttributeA, const __int32AttributeB) const 
{
try {
            return AnObject(AttributeA, AttributeB);  // recursive call
 } 
...
```

`SetMyAttributes` seems to be a useless function since all your data members are `const` and the fact that you return a `const` object by value.

*Normally*, You can only initialize a `const` data member in the constructor initialization list. You can't modify them afterwards.

Same *uselessness* applies to these (except if you have something else, out of the norm, up your sleeves:

```
const AnObject AnObject::SetAttributeA(const std::string AttributeA) const;
const AnObject AnObject::SetAttributeB(const __int32 AttributeB) const;
const AnObject AnObject::SetMyAttributes (const std::string AttributeA, const __int32 AttributeB) const;
```

---

If you are talking of a completely immutable class, you wouldn't have any setters. However, I suggest you read everything here: [`const correctness`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

Comment: That, and returning a constant by value. It's not like someone would accidentally try to modify a temporary...

Comment: @IInspectable... THanks, added